# googlesheet package does not allow me to sign in googlesheet in my Shiny App

Tags: google-sheets, shiny, package

Whenever I am trying to connect my Shiny app to Google sheet I get the message:
Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

It used to work but it looks like Google blocked the application recently. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the newer google sheet package by Jenny Bryan, googlesheets4 (https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could get connection to my GoogleDrive,

Comment: I installed/upgraded needed packages and wrote the following code: drive_auth(email="MyEmail@gmail.com")
sheets_auth(token = drive_token())
(DRIVE = drive_get("HCAbooking"))
SPE = read_sheet(DRIVE,  range = "spe")

Comment: After authentication, if you just run "DRIVE <- drive_get("MySpeadSheet")" does it create the variable? Can you inspect and see if it is loading the correct sheetkey? Also instead of read_sheet, try sheets_read.

Answer (score 1):

forget about the comment..

I tried googlesheets4 and it looks promising. I could reach my googleDrive but I am not able to read any sheet. Not even using sheets_examples, which is weird.

I tried:

```
drive_auth(email="MyEmail@gmail.com")
sheets_auth(token = drive_token())
(DRIVE = drive_get("MySpeadSheet"))
SPE = read_sheet(DRIVE,  range = "MySheet")
```

I have tried different ways to get my sheet with "read_sheet" (including sheets_examples) but every time I get the following error:

```
Error in parse(df$cell, ctype, ...) : is_string(ctype) is not TRUE
```